# Session timeout or application restart or worker process recycled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-ec2, iis-7

We have application hosted on aws EC2 IIS7 (Windows server 2008).

Since last one month or so we are facing abrupt sign out issue. When it occures it sign out all the logged in user. Same application is hosted on staging server it works fine. We have monitor Windows log and IIS log nothing suspecious item found.

We have configured session state as sessionstate `mode="inproc" timeout = 120`. (Session timeout or application restart or worker process recycled) occures at random time. sometime it occures withing seconds sometimes it works more than 5 min!

Application Virtual directory is under Default web site in IIS.

Can anyone give heads up to investigate this issue?

Comment: do you have separate application pool for application or it is shared with other hosted application?

Comment: Site is in defaultAppPool. But there is only one site so no problem of other application causing application pool to restart.

Comment: what is time interval of application pool recycling?

Comment: regular time interval is 1740 min

Comment: enable logging for non-configured recycling events so you will get sure that issue is with application pool or something else. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753412(v=ws.10).aspx